# Typehint that a type variable belongs to the subclass (for PyCharm linter)

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, linter

I am wondering about a PyCharm (2020.3) linter's warning thrown when I initialize an object from a type-variable that may represent a super-class or a sub-class with not-matching `__init__` signatures. I wonder:

- ...because I clearly type hint whether I am in case of the super-class or the sub-class
- ...and I wonder, because there actually is one combination to define and type-check the type-variable that does not lead to a warning. The thing is, I cannot see a difference to the other combinations.

But let the example speak. The following shows the one combination that does NOT lead to the warning (namely: `s_type = s.__class__` and `issubclass(s_type, Sub)`):

```py
class Sup:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class Sub(Sup):
    def __init__(self, sub_val: int = 0) -> None:
        _ = sub_val
        super().__init__()


def foobar(s: Sup) -> Sup:
    s_type = s.__class__  # linter would fail on `s_type = type(s)`
    if issubclass(s_type, Sub):  # linter would fail on `s_type == Sub`
        return s_type(42)
    else:
        return s_type()
```

In case, I use `s_type = type(s)` or `s_type == Sub`, PyCharm warns me about `42` as `Unexpected Argument`. Is there any language-inherent reason for this or am I just facing limitations of the PyCharm linter?

### Appendix

#### Failing Case `s_type = type(s)`

[image]

#### Failing Case `s_type == Sub`

[image]

Comment: You're having this problem because you've broken the Liskov substitution principle - Sub is *not* a drop-in replacement for Sup.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi :) Thanks for the fast response! At which point do I break with the principle? `foobar` works on `Sup`-objects as well as `Sub`-objects, right?

Comment: Only if it explicitly distinguishes between them.

Comment: You mean on return, or in the if-else-clause? I am on a loss here... :D

Comment: I mean in the if else... where it explicitly distinguishes them. What did you think issubclass was doing? If Sub properly subclassed Sup, you wouldn't need to discriminate.

Comment: Hmm, stupid me doesn't get in which way `Sub` is not properly subclassing `Sup`. It just adds one property to `Sup` (basically). This seems to be a usual pattern.

Or would you say, it is illegal to implement a special behaviour for `Sub`-objects in a function that is defined for all `Sup` objects?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I disagree that he violated it. Subclasses can extend the behavior of a superclass, and adding optional arguments to a method is a valid extension, since it always accepts the superclass's syntax.

Comment: However, explicitly testing class membership in functions is poor OO design. The right way to do this is to add a `foobar()` method to the classes.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, this is the better design - thanks for the hint (though it generates some boiler-plate code in my actual use case). Still, any idea what happens with the linter?

Comment: The linter has to guess the type of `s_type`. Its best guess is that it's `Sup` because of the type hint for `s`.

Comment: Maybe you could add a new variable `s_sub_type: Sub = s_type` and then call `s_sub_type(42)`

Comment: @Barmer As mentioned, with the code shared it already works w/o warning. I am just wondering what substituting `s.__class__` with `type(s)` or `issubclass(s_type, Sub)` with `s_type == Sub` changes for the linter to then produce the warning...